# Text along path decoration with white background

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, decorations

I want to have some text appear along a line but not be obstructed by the line itself. I tried the following:

```latex
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.text}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
  \addplot[mark=none,
  dotted,
  decoration={
    text along path,
    text={{My text \(\alpha\)}{}},
    text align={center},
    raise=-0.5ex},
  postaction={decorate},
  ]
  {x^2};

  % The following has the correct fill but then the text is even more mis-aligned
  % \addplot[mark=none,
  % dotted,
  % decoration={
  %   text effects along path,
  %   text={{My text \(\alpha\)}{}},
  %   text align={center},
  %   raise=-0.5ex,
  %   text effects/.cd,
  %   every character/.style={fill=white, yshift=-0.5ex}},
  % postaction={decorate},
  % ]
  % {x^2};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

But the text in the first try is obstructed by the line and is not 100% aligned with it (it does not curve correctly along it). For my second try, the text has the correct background (white) so the line no longer obstructs the text, but the text is even more mis-aligned with the curve.

How can I fix these issues?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you would like to achieve?

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.text}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
 \addplot[mark=none,
   dotted,
   decoration={
     text effects along path,
     text={My text {\(\alpha\)}},
     text align={center},
     raise=-0.5ex,
     text effects/.cd,
     characters={text along path, fill=white},
     },
   postaction={decorate},
   ]
   {x^2};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Exactly! Thanks for this. What does `character widths={text along path}` do exactly? Removing it doesn't seem to change the output.

Comment: @Tohiko You're right it's useless, I think it's a remnant of the attempts I did.